# How to determine which country/ state/ region/ city/ locality lies inside a leaflet polygon | rectangle | circle etc

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet, openstreetmap

How can I determine which country, state, region, city or locality lies inside a leaflet shape (polygon | rectangle | circle etc) created by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for **Reverse gecoding**. Leaflet does not provide gecoding services,but you can find similar example [here.](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/reverse-geocoding.html)

Google Geocoding service provide results in JSON format but you may need to pay for extra quotas.

Sample link:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452

**Updated with Stack Snippet:**

```js
window.cb = function cb(json) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Country:' + json.address.country + '|' + 'State:' + json.address.state + '|' + 'County:' + json.address.county + '|' + 'City:' + json.address.city;
}

window.getLocation = function getLocation() {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?json_callback=cb&format=json&lat=40.714224&lon=-73.961452&zoom=27&addressdetails=1';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);

};
```

```css
.myText {font-weight:bold;font-size:1.0em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="getLocation();" name="search" class='myText'>Get Location!</button>
<p id="result" class='myText'></p>
```

Comment: I am using nominatim reverse geocoder with leaflet but it doesnt offer any such functionality.

Comment: It does provides, refer this [documenations](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding). Example:http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=52.5487429714954&lon=-1.81602098644987&zoom=18&addressdetails=1